# How can I have a subtitle in a menu in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, menu, picker

What I am going after is shown in the standard stocks app.
[image]

So a menu which can be opened, but the current selection is shown in grey.

So far I got:

[image]

```
Picker("Volglijst toont\nPrijswijziging", systemImage: "chart.line.uptrend.xyaxis", selection: $selectedOption) {
    Text("Prijswijziging").tag(0)
    Text("Procentuele wijziging").tag(1)
    Text("Marktkapitalisatie").tag(2)
}.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

But I can't get the selection to show up in grey as per example.

It looks like SwiftUI does not yet support this option. On UIMenu you seem to have a subtitle attribute. Not sure if that will help.

Comment: SwiftUI Menu (the SwiftUI equivalent of UIMenu) supports nesting menus. I'm not sure if Picker does though.

Comment: add 2 Text elements in a row inside the button's content inside a menu in swiftui

Comment: Can you show me a for example. I don't think it will make the second text gray.

Answer (score 0):

Pickers work well with enums, so I recommend creating an enum structure to hold your options. You could make this extend String to use the raw values as your headings for the option. I also added CaseIterable and Identifiable to iterate through the elements for later usage. The calculated attribute `id` is required by the Identifiable protocol. If all your titles are unique you can simply use them as ids.

```
enum Options: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case option1 = "Option 1"
    case option2 = "Option 2"
    case option3 = "Option 3"
    
    var id: String { return self.rawValue }
}
```

With that in place, you can create a `@State` variable at the root of your view class to hold the selected option.

```
@State private var selectedOption: Options = .option1  // Specify default option
```

Then the Menu element can use this enum as its option. **Placing the Button view with two Text and an Image element as its label will produce the look you are looking for.**

```
Menu("Menu", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle") {
    Picker(selection: $selectedOption) {
        ForEach(Options.allCases) { option in
            Text(option.rawValue).tag(option)
        }
    } label: {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Selector")
            Text(selectedOption.rawValue)
            Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
        })
   }
   .pickerStyle(.menu)
}
```

This should look like you wanted:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that the displayed subtitle needs to correspond to the value selected in the picker.

Comment: Yep, that's right I just used the previous example. That is pretty easy to implement. Just replace the text in the second Text view to fit your use case

Comment: Shouldn't your answer show how to put the correct subtitle instead of simply hardcoding a value?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added some more details now.